# Would you consider "sound idea" (usable as) a pun?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, puns

Today I read this comment in the Csound mailing list <sup>[see full post](http://csound.1045644.n5.nabble.com/Csound-Simple-Desktop-player-for-csound-files-td5744490.html#a5744495)</sup> (emphasis mine):

> The interface could be polished, IMO, but **the idea is sound** [...]

it took me (as a German native speaker) a while to understand its meaning. Then I remembered that there is also the adjective [*sound*](http://www.dict.cc/?s=sound). Because the Csound mailing list is dedicated to sound and also the post subject could be meant here, I thought it could be also an *intended* ambiguity.

Is it therefore reasonable to expect that the pun "sound idea" (for *"idea for a specific sound"* and *"reasonable idea"*) would work for English speakers?

Comment: I'm not rolling on the floor laughing, but it is a perfectly serviceable pun.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a native English speaker would understand the pun, especially if you emphasized the word **sound**.

(It's a rather clever one, by the way.)

Comment: *`It's a rather clever one, by the way`* -- you mean the original one on the mailing list?

Comment: I meant generally, the pun on sound in sound idea.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, "the idea is sound" or "a sound idea" is a commonly used phrase. Therefore, I don't think most individuals would notice it as a pun.

Comment: I thought of using it in a musical context ;-)

Comment: In a musical context...Yes! THAT would be a recognizable pun. :)